# How to set conditional color range using np where python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have a data frame that looks like:

`print(file.head())`

```
            miRNAs    baseMean  log2FoldChange          padj
0    hsa-miR-31-5p  221.442806       -7.037259  4.360127e-27
1   hsa-miR-337-5p   14.711123       -5.790422  4.556183e-01
2  hsa-miR-196b-5p  162.278255       -5.652917  1.365264e-3
3   hsa-miR-584-5p    6.430919       -5.554578  4.077578e-04
4  hsa-miR-196a-5p  455.152841       -5.361830  1.019622e-59
```

What I want to do is to set the color range for the `file['padj']` column like below:

```
file['padj'] > 0.01 #gray
file['padj'] <= 0.01 #red
file['padj'] <= 0.0001 #orange
```

I tried to do this using `np.where` but only for one of the conditions.

```
p = file.plot.scatter(x='baseMean',y='log2FoldChange',c=np.where(np.abs(file['padj'])>0.01, 'gray', 'b'), logx=True)

# specifying horizontal line type
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'r', linestyle = '-')
plt.show()
```

I could not manage to define multiple conditions to `np.where` - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a color column like so:

```
file['color'] = 'gray'
file.loc[file['padj']<=0.01, 'color'] = 'red'
file.loc[file['padj']<=0.0001, 'color'] = 'orange'
```

and plot like this:

```
plt.scatter(file['baseMean'], file['log2FoldChange'], color=file['color'])
```

#edit:
hacky way to generate legend:

```
for label, color in zip(['>0.01', '<=0.01', '<=0.0001'], ['gray', 'red', 'orange']):
    plt.scatter([],[], c=color,label=label)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works perfectly. Is it also possible to add the defined colors as a color bar next to the main plot?

Comment: @Apex see my edit